# Remove <span class="price"> tag from formatPrice

Tags: magento

how can I remove/turn off `<span class="price">...</span>` from

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
```

in

```
 <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
```

i was change last argument to false and price print without `<span class="price">...</span>`
so I wonder how can I do in

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
```

I dont want change core file.
Thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite the Checkout Helper (Data.php) to your Namespace, to overwrite this function :

```
public function formatPrice($price)
{
    return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($price);
}
```

replace it with

```
public function formatPrice($price,$includeContainer = false)
{
    return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($price,$includeContainer);
}
```

Then you'll just need this :

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?
```

to Hide the span and :

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice(),true) ?
```

to get it back.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `strip_tags()` in PHP instead.

Comment: This worked great for exactly what I needed. I think this should be the actual answer. It's quick and clean to implement. No need to mess with additional files to over ride the functions.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this really helped me a lot. With this solution you don't need to change the magento core files. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, when using

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($price);
```

to get $price in local format, it prints $price which is enclosed by `<span class=”price”></span>`. In some case, this is not very pratical. If you don’t like this `<span>` tag much, you can use this method:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($price, false);
```

http://ntuan16.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/how-to-use-formatprice-without-tag/